# Meteor: Profile update fails mysteriously

Tags: collections, meteor, updates

I'm building a Meteor application and want users to be able to update/set their name. I've got the code set up, and everything seems to be working except that it mysteriously fails on the update. Here's my code:

**Template**

```
<template name="_editName">
  {{#ionModal focusFirstInput=true customTemplate=true}}
    <form id="updateName">
      <div class="bar bar-header bar-stable">
        <button data-dismiss="modal" type="button" class="button button-clear button-assertive">Cancel</button>
        <h2 class="title">Update your name</h2>
        <button type="submit" class="button button-positive button-clear">Save</button>
      </div>
      <div class="content has-header overflow-scroll list">
        <label class="item item-input">
          <input type="text" id="firstName" placeholder="Given Name">
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input">
          <input type="text" id="lastName" placeholder="Surname">
        </label>
      </div>
    </form>
  {{/ionModal}}
</template>
```

**Client-side code**

```
Template._editName.events({
  'submit #updateName': function(event, template) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('Submitted');
    var firstName = document.getElementById('firstName').value;
    var lastName = document.getElementById('lastName').value;

    Meteor.call('editName', firstName, lastName, function(error) {
      if (error) {      
        throw new Error(error.reason);
      } else {
        Router.go('profile');
      }
    });
    IonModal.close();
    IonKeyboard.close();
  }
});
```

**Server-side code**

```
Meteor.methods({
    'editName': function(firstName, lastName) {
        console.log(firstName); // returns expected value
        console.log(lastName); // returns expected value
        Meteor.users.update({_id: this.userId}, {$set: {
            'profile.firstName': firstName,
            'profile.lastName': lastName
        }});
        Meteor.users.findOne({_id: this.userId}, {fields: {
        'profile.firstName': 1, _id: 0}}); // returns undefined
    }
});
```

Everything works as it should: On submit, the function gets the field values, calls the method on the server, successfully passing the field values. The update *seems* to be working as no error is thrown. However, the 'profile.firstName' returns undefined and does not show up in my template.

I'm using the accounts-base package and aldeed:collection2. I have the following schema set up:

```
Schema.UserProfile = new SimpleSchema({
    firstName: {
        type: String,
        regEx: /^[a-zA-Z-]{2,25}$/,
        optional: true
    },
    lastName: {
        type: String,
        regEx: /^[a-zA-Z]{2,25}$/,
        optional: true
    }
});
```

I have absolutely no idea what's going wrong and would appreciate every help!

Comment: Meteor.users.findOne({_id: **this.userId**}... will only work if the user executing this call has been properly logged in otherwise this.userID will be empty of course. The next thing is did you check via `meteor mongo` if the profile has been set properly?

Comment: Also, you can't mix inclusion (1) and exclusion (0) in the fields option.

Comment: @Meteorpoly Thanks for the quick reply! I'm using the accounts-base package and just double-checked: The user is logged in properly, `console.log(this.userId)` returns the proper user ID.
Do you mean running `meteor mongo` in the terminal? Or how do I check that?

Comment: Ok but what does mongodb say, has the update made it to the db?

Comment: @saimeunt Thanks for the hint, but you actually can: _The exception is that you may specify _id: 0 in an inclusion specifier, which will leave _id out of the result object as well._ ([Meteor docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/fieldspecifiers)).

Comment: @Meteorpoly This is my first time using `meteor mongo`, didn't know this existed. Nope, it doesn't show. I'm using aldeed:collection2 btw, could that have to do with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've checked your code and I found *multiple issues* which need your attention.

Please get the fixed project from **[here](https://github.com/meteorpoly/sof-account-customization)**  and follow the instructions to get and run it.

The main issues were:

1. In your collection's schema definition you first specified the UserSchema and referenced the UserProfile schema. Since the UserProfile didn't exist by the time you referenced it, the code was failing silently. Maybe you address this with the package owner for a better error and reference check handling.
2. You should definitely read upon meteor's databinding since under the profile.html templates you did quite a few mistakes
3. Initialize your profile schema on user creation:

```js
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user) {
  // We're enforcing at least a profile skeleton object to avoid needing to check
  // for its existence later.
  // this file should reside on Server (e.g.  [root]/server/accounts.js)
  profile = {
    firstName: '',
    lastName: '',
    birthday: '',
    sex: '',
    grade: '',
    country: '',
    hostel: '',
    house:''
  }

  user.profile = profile;

  return user;
});
```

4. Expose the published fields for your custom profile

```js
Meteor.publish('userProfile', function() {
  if(!this.userId) { 
    return null
  } else {
    return Meteor.users.find({_id: this.userId}, {
      fields: {
        username: 1,
        'profile.firstName': 1,
        'profile.birthday': 1,
        'profile.sex': 1,
        'profile.grade': 1,
        'profile.country': 1,
        'profile.hostel': 1,
        'profile.house': 1
      }
    });
  }
```

5. General meteor / JS coding standard issues which you will want to review
6. There are also other things you would like to check like, variable scoping, unit testing, performance etc. before you go to production with this.

As a general rule (from my experience at least) I would always start at a bare minimum and avoiding to use complex packages without a solid foundation of the framework at hand. This will save you a lot of debugging and frustration like this in the future :).

Please **accept this answer** as soon as you have verified it so I can **delete it** again from my github account.

Good luck.

Comment: Perfect. Absolutely great. Thank you sooooo much! :)
This is my first meteor project and I still need to learn a lot. I'll definitely have a look at the other issues as well.
I've cloned your repo, feel free to delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Please see my working example code below for you reference:

**User detail template markup**

```html
      {{#with currUser}}
        <form class="edit-todo" id="edit-user">
          Username:
          <input type="text" name="username" value="{{profile.name}}" />
          Firstname:
          <input type="text" name="firstname" value="{{profile.firstname}}" />
          Lastname:
          <input type="text" name="lastname" value="{{profile.lastname}}" />
          <button type="submit" style="width: 100px;height:50px">Save user</button>
        </form>
      {{/with}}
```

**User detail template code**

```js
Template.UsersDetail.events({
    'submit form#edit-user': function(e, tmpl) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var firstname = tmpl.find('input[name=firstname]').value;
        var lastname = tmpl.find('input[name=lastname]').value;
        var userId = Meteor.userId();

        Meteor.call('editName', userId, firstname, lastname, function(error) {
            if (error) {
                throw new Error(error.reason);
            } else {
                Router.go('users.detail', {
                    _id: userId
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
Template.UsersDetail.helpers({
    currUser: function() {
        return Meteor.users.findOne({
            _id: Meteor.userId()
        });
    }
});
```

**Server method for name updates**

```js
/*****************************************************************************/
/* Server Only Methods */

Meteor.methods({
    'editName': function(userId, firstName, lastName) {
        Meteor.users.update({_id: userId}, {$set: {
            'profile.firstname': firstName,
            'profile.lastname': lastName
        }});
        console.log(Meteor.users.findOne({_id: this.userId}).profile.lastname);// returns the proper name
    }
});
```

[image: Result]

Comment: I wish that did it, but no. Must be something else. Something must be inferring with the update function.

Comment: Well... if possible provide your project (or a reproduc. test project) in a public github repo or meteorpad, otherwise it is difficult to investigate further.

Comment: I'll see what I can do, I'm pretty new to all this (coding). Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: I managed to upload it to github (I think). This is the [repo](https://github.com/connor-baer/phoenix-app). Please have a look if you don't mind.

Comment: Ok I will check it tomorrow

Comment: @ConnorBär you're welcome, please note that I've deleted the repo from my github repositories now.